# mysqli_fetch_object - how to get sum of values

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

I think there might be an easy solution for my problem. I'm trying to get the sum of values returned by a mysqli_query call. Maybe someone can help me fixing this problem?

In my database, there are INT values.

```
function get_einkommen($user, $var){
global $db;
$sum;
$sum2=0;
$query = "SELECT $var FROM kartedb WHERE besetzt_von_user = '$user'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {

    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

        $sum=intval($obj->$var);
        echo $sum;
    }
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $sum2=$sum2+$sum[$i];
        echo $sum;
    }

mysqli_free_result($result);
}
}
```

from the first echo, I get 1121110 (so theese are the values in the db.), but from the second echo I only see 0000000000 . Even the for-loop isn't nice, don't know how to handle it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You aren't assigning to any array in the while-loop, but overwriting `$sum` over and over...

Comment: Obligatory comment about using parameterized queries instead of blindly inserting variable values into a sting.

Comment: If you're only wanting to check the sum of one column, why not just use MySQL's `SUM()` aggregate function instead of looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I fixed it, in this way it's working...

```
function get_einkommen($user, $var){
global $db;
$query = "SELECT sum($var) AS var_sum FROM kartedb WHERE besetzt_von_user = '$user'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['var_sum'];
echo $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting sum over and over again instead of adding to it.

```
function get_einkommen($user, $var){
global $db;
$sum;
$sum2=0;
$query = "SELECT $var FROM kartedb WHERE besetzt_von_user = '$user'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {

    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

        $sum += intval($obj->$var);
        echo $sum;
    }
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $sum2=$sum2+$sum[$i];
        echo $sum;
    }

mysqli_free_result($result);
}
}
```

I think that this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could push the summing over to mysql.

select sum(column) from kartedb where besetzt_von_user = '$user';

Then you only have a single, precomputed sum, to retrieve.

Maybe not a big difference if the number of rows are small, but less bytes over the write to be sent in the event it's a large sum.